# Searching through and replacing an element in 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out a way to search though a 2D array to find a certain word and then replacin that word.

For example:

```
pets = [['I', 'have', 'a', 'cat'], ['She', 'has', 'a', 'pet', 'cat']]
```

I need a way to search for the word 'cat' and replace it with the word 'dog'.

Comment: and what have you tried? because so far it sounds like you are passing over homework.

Comment: Is it only 2 sentences in `pets` or there are more sentences?

Comment: So far I've tried using indexing the position but I wanted another way in case the words I'm looking for are'nt in the same position each time. And as for the second question, it depends on the user input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to check all elements, and replace those that are `'cat'` with `'dog'` :

```
pets = [['I', 'have', 'a', 'cat'], ['She', 'has', 'a', 'pet', 'cat']]

new_pets = [[p if p.lower()!='cat' else 'dog' for p in s] for s in pets]
print(new_pets) # => [['I', 'have', 'a', 'dog'], ['She', 'has', 'a', 'pet', 'dog']]
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Glad to help :).

Answer (score 0):

Using [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
pets = [[val.replace('cat', 'dog') for val in row] for row in pets]
```